# Overloading, optional arguments, or something else?

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to validate a field's value according to two different validation rules:

1. An object of my own which contains a regex and a range (for string it's length range).
2. A list of possible values.

So I can do this:

```
public static bool Validate(string fieldValue, string fieldType, ValidationParameters validationParameters)
{
...
}    
public static bool Validate(string fieldValue, string fieldType, string[] possibleValues)
{
...
}
```

But that requires the user to ungracefully `if`.
I can also do this:

```
public static bool Validate(string fieldValue, string fieldType, ValidationParameters validationParameters=null,string[] possibleValues=null)
{
...
}
```

Now the user can just send he's data, without redundant `if`, But I can't make sure `validationParameters` or `possibleValues` (one of them) got a value.

Is there a third option, one in which the user won't have to check which method he uses, but I won't have to worry that he doesn't send any of the two fields (in code, not documentation)?
If not, which way of the two above is better (less error-prone and more elegant)?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess I don't see what you mean by the first option requiring the user to "ungracefully if".

Comment: @Mckay (and the other first responders): Wouldn't you agree that if the second option didn't have the "minor issue" of making sure one of the fields has value, it would have been much more elegant?

Comment: Much more elegant? No. A little more elegant? Sure. But it's a big "if". It seems like not a "minor issue" to me

Comment: @McKay - "Minor issue" I agree it's not minor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would do two overloaded methods.  The main reasoning for this is:

> But I can't make sure validationParameters or possibleValues (one of them) got a value.

Optional arguments, in my opinion, should be exactly that: *optional*.  Making two optional arguments where one is required seems like a problematic design choice.

Your main reasoning for avoiding this seems to be:

> But that requires the user to ungracefully if.

However, I don't see the problem.  The user is going to have to construct either the string collection (which, I personally, would either make `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `string[]`, or do `params string[] possibleValues`) or the `ValidationParameters`.  If they already need to construct the arguments to pass, adding an `if` conditional seems unnecessary (each path could just call the validation).

Comment: There are still things in your answer I need to think through, but the user gets both together (there isn't a "path", it's a web-service in which you get all the data for this usage in one shot...)

Comment: @Oren: The web service has to return one or the other option, though - so the user is going to know which they're getting, I would think...  If the webservice is returning BOTH sets of information, I would personally put both sets into a single class, and pass an instance of that into the method here, so the user never has to decipher the information.

Answer (score 2):

If they are validating by different concepts, they should probably be named differently. Say, `ValidateByValidationParameters` and `ValidateByPossibleValues`. Now the question is, why wouldn't you want the caller to carefully select which one he is using?

Comment: Please refer to my comment on the question.. Thanks (-:

Comment: @Oren A: The elegance comment?

Comment: (-: ahh.. Yeah. It's an answer to why I wouldn't want the caller to carefully select.. - Because in the second way he can avoid that. This was surely the way, if I could enforce exactly one of the values being not null.

Comment: @Oren A: If the methods are doing different things (as you say, "according to two different validation rules") they should be named differently.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't require that one of them is sent, I'd recommend the former option, but I don't understand what you mean by the fact that you don't like that the user has to "ungracefully if".

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the methods - as you said - or do something like this:

```
       enum TYPE { VAL_1, VAL_2 }

       void function(TYPE validateType, object o)
       {
        swich(validateType)
        { 
           case VAL_1:
              List<string> par = o List<String>;
              if(par != null)
              {
                 //...
              }
           break;

           case VAL_2:
              List<MyObject> par = o as List<MyObject>;
              if(par != null)
              {
                 //...
              }
          break;
        }
  }
```

Maybe it's not very typesafe, but somteimes useful.

At last - you can prepare single delegate method for every validation case and call those  methods (single or many) in one place.